# symfony2　Web サーバーの設定にてエラー

Tags: apache, symfony2

http://jobeet.symfony.gr.jp/day-1-starting-up-the-project.html#symfony-2-3-2

上記サイトを参考にsymfony2プロジェクト作成のWebサーバー設定を実施したところ
apacheエラーで起動できなくなってしまいました。

```
 Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
17:15:36  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
17:15:36  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
17:15:36  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
17:15:36  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
17:15:36  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
17:15:36  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

各設定は以下のようにしております。

【マシン】

> windows

【apache：httpd.conf】

```
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"  <Directory
 "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

【apache：httpd-vhosts.conf】

```
 　<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName jobeet.local
     DocumentRoot /var/www/jobeet/web
     DirectoryIndex app.php
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/jobeet-error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/jobeet-access.log combined
     <Directory "/var/www/jobeet/web">
         AllowOverride All
         Allow from All
      </Directory>  </VirtualHost>
```

【C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts】

`127.0.0.1 jobeet.local` 　←追記

【jobeetプロジェクト格納場所】

> C:\var\www\jobeet

以上の設定で、どこが間違っているかわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/12583　マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

Apache の設定ファイルのミスと見られます。末尾の `</VirtualHost>` が抜け落ちていませんか？Symfony を試すことが目的なら、バーチャルホストを設定しない方法もあります。

```
cd C:/xampp/htdocs
php symfony new my_project
```

でプロジェクトをつくり、`http://localhost/my_project/web/app_dev.php/app/example` にアクセスすれば「Homepage.」が表示されます。

Apache の設定に慣れていないと、ちょっとした設定ミスで Apache が動かないことはよくあるので、冷却時間をおいて、そのあいだは別のことに取り組むとよいかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
Symfony　は次のプロジェクトにて利用するため独学で勉強しようと思ったのですが、マシンがwindowsしかなく、コマンドもcygwinでやってまして・・・データアクセスまでできれば実施したいと思いjobeetを進めたかったのですが、環境構築すらままならない状況です（＾＾；

my_project にてHomepageは作成できましたので、一旦参考書等をみてからもう一度Apache設定みてみます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: VirtualBox と Vagrant による仮想マシンはいかがでしょうか？今の時代に Cygwin を使うメリットはあまり感じられません。